# A full-page wysiwyg editor for xhtml?

Tags: php, javascript, xhtml, cross-browser, wysiwyg

My client has a website which is currently semi-static html pages: it contains dynamic elements such as navigation and a media gallery, but the editable content is still stored straight into several static (x)html pages, that the client edits using Expression Web.

The site in itself is ready for content/style/layout separation, but the client isn't: he wants full-page, wysiwyg editing that allows him everything (color, font size, background (highlighting), images (positioning and resizing); except font family, which he wants kept to sans-serif at all times.

The full-page bit is the important one: there are tons of wysiwygs out there that do everything I mentioned, *except for the full-page bit*. What I need to find, or make, is something that will resemble Expression Web/Frontpage/Dreamweaver: an editor with a **toolbar at the top**, and that can **edit any part of the page *I specify***.

It also needs (to add to the Utopia), full xhtml+css support so it doesn't break the content, or alternatively, to edit in a markup language that can be easily translated into styled xhtml (using php or js). This is a live website, so *of course* it needs to be cross-browser, both for input and output.

Finally, it would be nice if it was open-source.

Comment: I don't wish to be insulting to you, or your client, but I think it's your responsibility to advise your client when they're asking for the impossible, Utopian or plain insane. Suggested reading from A List Apart: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getting-to-no/ and http://www.alistapart.com/articles/no-one-nos-learning-to-say-no-to-bad-ideas/

Comment: 'The client' is a term I use generically to protect privacy. In that case, it is a (close) relative, and therefore if I don't find a solution to that problem that conforms to the goals above, I'll be obliged to keep maintaining (repairing it when Expression Web stuffs it up) that site until the end of time or when it becomes obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest using Content Management Systems (CMS) that support in-place editing of page elements?

**Nuggetz**

- http://www.nuggetz.co.uk/
- Demo: http://demo.nuggetz.co.uk/ (login: admin / password: password)

**Apostrophe Now!**

- http://www.apostrophenow.com/
- Demo: http://demo.apostrophenow.com/ (login: admin / password: demo)

Comment: nuggetz is a bit slow, and all it does is provide a wysiwyg in a lightbox.
Apostrophe Now! is closer to what I meant, but not quite.

Comment: what else do you need? .. oh btw, just fyi, at here reputation points (aka votes) are the currency. the more you are willing to vote/accept people answers, the more people are willing to answer your questions. just a small advise as a welcome msg ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The concept is a bit strange, but I'll get used to it. I optimally need a toolbar at the top of the screen so it doesn't break/change the layout when editing. Apart from that, that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm i don't think that you can find something like your description. You need some sort of dreamweaver running inside the browser. Probably CkEditor pointed by Micahel is the most advanced editor out there and you are right if you use it to edit an entire site in place maybe the universe explode...

Comment: Yes, that's what I feared. I'm gonna invent something, then: taking an wysiwyg apart and fitting back the parts how I want: top toolbar, inline editing, no font change.